# Programmatically translation of the terms of woocommerce with wpml

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wpml

I have developed an importer of woocommerce products and I need to translate the products and of course the related taxonomy.

For the translations I decided to use wpml and unfortunately I can't assign the German language to the translated taxonomy.

Unfortunately I can't even find help in solving my problem in the WPML support forum and the code available online doesn't work for me.

```
global $sitepress;

$args_it = array( 'description'=> $term_name_it, 'slug' => $term_slug, 'parent' => 0 );
$args_de = array( 'description'=> $term_name_de, 'slug' => $term_slug. "-de", 'parent' => 0 );

$term_it = wp_insert_term( $term_name_it, 'product_cat', $args_it );
$term_de = wp_insert_term( $term_name_de, 'product_cat', $args_de );

// get the trid from the original
$trid = $sitepress->get_element_trid($term_it['term_id'], 'tax_product_cat');

// associate the translated term to the original
$sitepress->set_element_language_details($term_de['term_id'], 'tax_product_cat', $trid, 'de', $sitepress->get_default_language());
```

At the moment, using this code, I don't have any errors, but it shows me all the terms as if they were all in Italian and not translations.

Answer (score 2):

I realized that $trid was NULL and that the "wp_icl_translations" table in element_id saved the value "term_taxonomy_id" instead of "term_id".

Below the code that solved my problem. Have fun.

```
global $sitepress;


$args_it = array( 'description'=> $term_name_it, 'slug' => $term_slug, 'parent' => 0 );
$args_de = array( 'description'=> $term_name_de, 'slug' => $term_slug. "-de", 'parent' => 0 );

$term_it = wp_insert_term( $term_name_it, 'product_cat', $args_it );
$term_de = wp_insert_term( $term_name_de, 'product_cat', $args_de );

// get the trid from the original
$trid = $sitepress->get_element_trid($term_it['term_taxonomy_id'], 'tax_product_cat');

if (! empty($trid)) {
     // associate the translated term to the original
     $sitepress->set_element_language_details($term_de['term_taxonomy_id'], 'tax_product_cat', $trid, 'de', $sitepress->get_default_language());
     $sitepress->set_element_language_details($term_it['term_taxonomy_id'], 'tax_product_cat', $trid, 'it', $sitepress->get_default_language());
} else {
     // $trid is NULL 
}
```

Comment: THANKS! I came across your explanation after 4 or 5 hours of research... I also made the mistake by wanting to pass "term_id" instead of "term_taxonomy_id"

Comment: I also made a mistake for the "trid" parameter... I called "get_element_trid" w/ the id of the translations and not the main term... your comment put me on the track! Maybe this can help others